# Connection between Fabric network and Node.js client app

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have currently running a Hyperledger Fabric network version 1.4.3 whose certificates were generated by Fabric CA and I would like to attach a node.js client app. For this I have 2 questions:

1- Is there any peculiarities to this type of certificate or a simple client type certificate should do the trick and

2- As my network is already up and running must I perform a channel update to include this newly generated certificate to the desired MSP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to your questions

> Answer for 1)simple client type certificate generated by fabric-ca or
>   cryptogen tool is enough for your sdk to interact with fabric unless
>   if you use attribute-based accessing

---

> Answer for 2) I client certificates need not inform to MSP's that's
>   the power of PKI  simply generate as many as you can and interact with
>   the fabric